# onClick event for Div content

Tags: javascript, css, xpages

Here is my simple xPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:div
        style="border-color:rgb(255,0,0);border-style:solid;border-width:thin"
        id="div1" styleClass="divStyleClass1">
        <xp:label value="Label" id="label1" styleClass="labelStyleClass">
        </xp:label>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert(thisEvent.target.className);
if(thisEvent.target.className=="divStyleClass1"){
    thisEvent.target.className="divStyleClass2";
} else {
    thisEvent.target.className="divStyleClass1";
}]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

I want to change DIV styleClass by onClick event. And it works fine till I click on any element inside the DIV, e.g. on the label. Obviously thisEvent.target points to the label object and it fails.

So how to fix it so it changes DIV styleClass regardless of where and what you click inside?

Comment: I am not aware of xpage. However, from html and e.g. jQuery I know you can use a function like `closest`. Maybe this helps you. (http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: DIV id is unknown. So this way I need to use thisEvent.xxxxx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possibility is to use the `currentTarget` property of the event rather than `target`. `currentTarget` contains the node the event handler is attached to.

---

If that's not sufficient, you might be able to do something like this:

```
var target = thisEvent.target;
while(target != null) {
  if(target.nodeName == "DIV") {
    break;
  }
  target = target.parentNode;
}
```

`target` will then contain the nearest ancestor node that is a div or `null`.

Comment: Both approaches are working well for question's XPage example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the target, check the element itself:

```
var div = document.getElementById("div1");
if(div.className == "divStyleClass1") {
    div.className = "divStyleClass2";
} else {
    div.className = "divStyleClass2";
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that DIV id is unknown. It's autogenerated with special formula in repeat control. So it can be DIV1, DIV2, DIV3, etc

Comment: are you sure the class is always one these two? @JohnGlabb

Comment: yes, I know the class I want to switch between when you click on the DIV. E.g. I want to change DIV background-color. But the code doesn't work if you click on any element inside the DIV